# How to use jabber-bot to connect to chat server

Tags: ruby, xmpp, chat

we have a private chat server running on one of the servers we own. for example: `company.server.com`. We connect to this with our chat clients on port `5223`.

How can I get Jabber-bot to connect to this chat? What if I want to connect to a particular room?

Below is what I have but it seems to just hang and do nothing. I believe there should be a property where I should provide the name of the server I'm connecting to but I can't find that property anyplace.

```
require 'rubygems'
require './jabber/bot'

# Create a public Jabber::Bot
config = {
  :jabber_id => 'name@mycompany.com',
  :password  => 'mypassword',
  :master    => 'name@mycompany.com',
  :presence  => :chat,
}

bot = Jabber::Bot.new(config)

# Give your bot a private command, 'rand'
bot.add_command(
  :syntax      => 'rand',
  :description => 'Produce a random number from 0 to 10',
  :regex       => /^rand$/
) { rand(10).to_s }


# Bring your new bot to life
bot.connect
```

Answer (score 1):

```
session = Jabber::Session.bind('account@host/resource', 'password')
```